# strpos issue not giving correct result

Tags: php

So I have this code :

```
$str1 = 'yabadabadoo';
$str2 = 'yaba';
if (strpos($str1,$str2)) {
    echo "\"" . $str1 . "\" contains \"" . $str2 . "\"";
} else {
    echo "\"" . $str1 . "\" does not contain \"" . $str2 . "\"";
}
```

Which gives me `"yabadabadoo" does not contain "yaba"`. Why? Shouldn't it give me the other result?

Answer (score 1):

Because the string is at index 0.
From the official documentation

> Warning
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

so you should change your if statement